# How class loading is done by using -Xbootclasspath/p:path?

Tags: java, dynamic-class-loaders

I've seen -Xbootclasspath/p:path being used for loading class dynamically can you please elaborate and explain by providing example.

Comment: Start by reading the Oracle documentation; i.e. the manual page on the `java` command and the document it links to on how the classpath works.

Comment: @StephenC : I went through Oracle documentaion site but, it was quite unclear about the usage. Thats the reason of posting the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

go to your command line and type java -X, to see the options available, -Xbootclasspath followed by path to comma seperated lists of jar files specified to prepend these classes before the standard jre classes. A use would be if you want to add patches affecting core runtime libraries.

Comment: Doesn't -Xbootclasspath *replace* the standard boot classpath in its entirety? Why do you say that they are *prepended*?

Comment: Looks like you can replace, append or prepend based on how you use it: `-Xbootclasspath:bootclasspath` files are used in place of; `-Xbootclasspath/a:path` files are appended to; `-Xbootclasspath/p:path` files are added in front of... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Comment: Note the "comma separated lists" statement is wrong. Multiple jars on Xbootclasspath are separated the same way as for standard classpath - semicolon in Windows, colon in Linux. The `java -X` provides hint with correct separator on each platform.